# Generate attribute members into string automatically from C++ class?

Tags: c++, string

I am programming in C++ (still a beginner), and I was wondering a question about generating automatically value members of class into string for example :

```
class Point
{
private:
int x;
int y;

public:
std::list<std::string> getValues();
}
```

In my opinion, I think I must code the function getValues, transform the ints into strings and put the string in a list and return the list, but my tutor asks me if there is a way to do this function automatically,without writting the code, and I don't know how to answer.

Because if we add a new member value (ex : int z), we will have to recode the function getValues().Apparently there is some way to do this in Java,but I was wondering if there is similar way into C++.

Best regards

Comment: another guess: your tutor wants you to store `x` and `y` in a dynamic data structure (e.g. `map<string,int>`) so that `getValues()` can iterate over the entries at run time.

Comment: But if I add a member attribute like double precision. The concept of the map<string,int> will be obselete ?

Comment: Even if I have already seen templates in some codes, I have never used or learned about templates. I will do some research and see if it can respond to the problems, thanks

Comment: Apart from pure academic interest, I would tell your tutor that attempting to bolt on reflexion on C++ structures is fundamentally a bad idea. It requires black magic (preprocessor or other external tools) and leads to hard to understand code. I would much prefer a *non-automatic* way without magic in a real code-base, because it terms of maintenance it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to say what your tutor really wanted from you, but if I were your tutor I would love you to learn about [Boost.Fusion Adapted Structures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html) and techniques it is based on (in particular typemaps).

Example with Boost.Fusion:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/define_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/fold.hpp>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT(
    (), Point,
    (int, x)
    (long, y)
    (double, z)
)

template <class Itr> struct collector_t
{
    using result_type = Itr;

    template <class T>
    Itr operator()(Itr itr, T const& val) const { *itr = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(val); return ++itr; }
};


int main()
{
    Point p {123, 456l, 123.456};

    // create and populate the resulting list using boost.fusion facilities
    std::list<std::string> strings;
    auto sink = std::back_inserter(strings);
    boost::fusion::fold(p, sink, collector_t<decltype(sink)>());

    // dump the resulting list to prove the example
    for (auto s: strings) std::cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will look for this even if it sounds a bit difficult for me for the moment. I am trying to work without external librairies like boost (just std) but I guess I will have to try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this automatically in C++. That would require reflection, i.e., code must be able to reason about the fields a class has. This is not possible in C++. It is possible in Java, so you are right, one can do this automatically in Java.

Comment: Then, please give some example code how to realize his function based on your link :). In addition, OP talked about adding a method for this struct. I am not sure if transforming the struct into a boost macro is a viable option. If it was, you could also just answer that OP should use `std::tuple` instead of a struct, then it is trivial, too.

Comment: I search about tuple http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple and I think It could be a good alternative,the only thing we have to know, is the correct order of the attributes in the tuple.

Comment: @bobah: *automatically* is impossible, in a way. You need to work-around the issue by (ab)using the preprocessor or an external parser/generator for now. There *are* proposals to add native compile-time reflexion to C++ that will really automate this; but those are still proposals. That being said, Boost.Fusion is for now the most elegant scheme... should automation really be needed (which I question).

Answer (score 1):

In a non-automated way: using visitation (compile-time).

```
class Point {
public:
    //
    // With visitation (names are optional)
    //
    template <typename Visitor>
    void visit(Visitor&& visitor) {
        visitor("x", x);
        visitor("y", y);
    }

    template <typename Visitor>
    void visit(Visitor&& visitor) const {
        visitor("x", x);
        visitor("y", y);
    }

    //
    // With tuples
    //
    auto as_tuple() -> std::tuple<int&, int&> {
        return std::tie(x, y);
    }

    auto as_tuple() const -> std::tuple<int const&, int const&> {
        return std::tie(x, y);
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Yes, those solutions require some more maintenance. However all the code is *exposed* without the need to mentally expand a macro. As a result, potential compilation error messages tend to be clearer and understanding is eased.

As for the maintenance burden ?

- you can automate (unit-test) the correlation of the two methods (make sure they both return the same number of members in the same order)
- automating detection of incomplete methods is slightly harder, but if a member is missing and tested it will show up too

*Note: I personally prefer the `as_tuple` version, it makes writing `==` and `<` so easy.*

*Note: detection of incomplete methods (missing members) can be attempted using `sizeof` and the ABI rules.*

Answer (score 0):

The question really has two parts:

1. Finding all members and
2. Converting them to string.

Finding members is not possible in pure C++, because it does not have any form of reflection. You could resort to special declaration macros using the standard preprocessor like [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html) does or you can use your own preprocessor like [OpenC++](http://opencxx.sourceforge.net/) or using the Clang front-end.

For converting to strings, the standard approach would then be like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T const &v) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << v;
    return s.str();
}
```

You can avoid typing this in and use [Boost.Lexical Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Note that C++11 also has [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), but it is only defined for numeric types and therefore not very useful for this purpose.